# How do I determine a dynamic range using Excel Standard 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to determine what the range of the data is dynamically so that I can successfully apply the sumproduct function without manually expanding the range anytime new data is included.

For example, I have a product column and a value column where for each product, I would like to load into a 3rd column, the highest value for that product.

[image]

The function that I am using is [image]

From what I highlighted in yellow, I would have to manually increase anytime new data is included which is why I am attempting to figure out how this can be done dynamically.  I am new to this feature of excel.  However, I did conduct some research in tutorials on using the OFFSET function and the MATCH function, but in attempting it, I would receive a #VALUE

Any feedback would be appreciated.  Thank you for taking the time in reading this.

Comment: Can you convert your data to a table (Ctrl+T)?

Comment: You are using fixed row numbers (`$2 $12`)so Excel will never adjust the sum automatically. Change your formula to `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((B2:B12=B2)*(C2:C12)))`, that is, remove the **$** sign from the row numbers. Excel will now adjust the formula if you add or delete any rows.

Comment: Thank you Big Ben.  Yeah, that appears to have worked.  I am not used to using tables, but I would imagine its best to use them.  In using the table, the function that I am using is =SUMPRODUCT(MAX((B$2:[PRODUCT]=B2)*(C$2:[VALUE]))) which appears to be working.  Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you OldBoy for the reply.  I would assume to apply what you shared at A2?  I thought the result would go out of range given row 3 and beyond would increment greater than 13 which I figured would result to #REF, but it turned that it didn't.  However, the results are not entirely accurate and I am not certain on why that is.  For instance, Orange at row 12 returned a value of 50 when it should be 100.  The function I have at row 12 using what you provided, `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((B12:B21=B12)*(C12:C21)))`.